# Approximation of an integral with balls

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let's say I have nonnegative functions $f \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^d)^+$ smooth and compactly supported and I have a set $A \subset \mathbb R^d$ of infinite Lebesgue measure. I would like to estimate the integral over balls of fixed radius $\ell > 0$; since $\mathbb R^d$ is $\sigma$-compact I can cover $A$ with countably many balls, i.e. there is a countable set $\mathcal S$ for which
$$ \int_A f(x)dx \leq \sum_{x_i \in \mathcal S} \int_{B_\ell(x_i)} f(x)dx. $$
But I would like to continue working with an integral; is it possible to get
$$ \int_A f(x)dx \leq \sum_{x_i \in \mathcal S} \int_{B_\ell(x_i)} f(x)dx \leq \int_A \left(\int_{B_\ell(x)}f(y)dy\right)dx? $$
(Or is there an upper bound up to a constant $C$ independent of $f$ but possibly depending on $\ell$?) I have no idea how to start - part of me thinks the answer is yes because I am replacing a Riemann type sum with an integral and I know also for instance that the average integral of a ball converges to its centre as the radius gets small, but the other part thinks these arguments should yield a constant with dependence on $f$.

Comment: From knowing only that "the covering of $A$ is countable and of fixed radius $l$" we can deduce nothing about how big $\sum_{x_i \in \mathcal S} \int_{B_\ell(x_i)} f(x)dx$ can get, since the overlapping of the balls from our covering can make this sum of integrals infinite for any given $A$ and nonzero function $f$ (so even in the case where $\int_A \left(\int_{B_\ell(x)}f(y)dy\right)dx \leq M$, where $M$ is finite and independent of the covering). 

So the constant you are looking for would have to depend on the covering somehow.

Comment: There exists a constant $N_d$ dependent only on the dimension $d$ (so not on $l$ or $f$), such that for every $A$ there exists a countable covering $S$ of $A$ with balls of given radius $l$, such that $$ \int_A f(x)dx \leq \sum_{x_i \in \mathcal S} \int_{B_\ell(x_i)} f(x)dx \leq N_d \cdot \int_{A +l} f(x)dx $$ where $A+l$ is the set of points with distance from $A$ not bigger than $l$.  I'm not sure whether that's what your question is about. I can explain this further if you want me to.

Comment: Also note that it is true that $$\lim_{l\rightarrow 0} \int_A \left(\int_{B_\ell(x)}f(y)dy\right)dx = \int_A f(x)dx$$ for any given $A$ and compactly supported bounded $f$.

Comment: Thanks, it looks so obvious now that the inequality between the sum and the integral can't be right. And on your second comment, I was hoping for something like the limit in your third - for me $f$ might be a function where there's sometimes good behaviour on balls and sometimes some good behaviour on $A$, so I was hoping for something like $$\int_A f(x)dx \leq C\int_A\left(\int_{B_\ell(x)} f(y)dy\right)dx, \, C > 0$$ for a fixed $\ell$ small enough and all $f$. But on this I am fairly sure the limit you wrote would converge depending on $f$ and so I don't think a fixed $\ell$ works.

Comment: Your comment was very helpful though in making me realize my mistake and so if you would like to write it down as a full answer I'd happily accept. The inequality with $N_d$ is not what I was looking for but I'm interested in reading about what $N_d$ is. (I'm guessing $N_d$ is an integer that describes the number of overlaps a ball might have with another but if $N_d$ is non-integer that would be interesting!)

Comment: What I meant to write in the equation with the limit is an average integral over a ball (the integral should be divided by the volume of the ball). Sorry, I can't edit it now.

Comment: Your guess about $N_d$ is correct, you can prove it with an appropriate version of Bosecovitch's covering theorem (treating the integral like a measure).

Comment: Thanks for the reference (not sure if I'll use it but an interesting result to know!) and all your explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From knowing that "the covering of $A$ is countable and of fixed radius $l$" we can say nothing about how big $\sum_{x_i \in \mathcal S} \int_{B_\ell(x_i)} f(x)dx$ can get, since the overlapping of the covering balls can make this sum of integrals infinitely big.
The problem with thinking about it as a "Riemann sum" is that such sums are disjoint, an your sum allows for infinite overlaps.

Maybe you could try a similar thing with disjoint (f.i. half-open) cubes instead of balls.